# Cannot filter Gmail API push notifications

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I was trying to get `Gmail inbox event` as a push notification for my application using Google Pub/Sub refering [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). Although I declare `labelIds` as `['INBOX']`, Gmail API sends notifications for all events (i.e. INBOX, SENT, IMPORTANT & etc). My python Code looks as below,

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
request = {
    'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
    'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/getNotification'
}
service.users().watch(userId='me',body=request).execute()
```

How can I get it notifications for `Inbox` event rather than all

Comment: I think you forgot labelFilterAction, checkout this https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.watch before writing code check the method structure in google api explorer, if you succeed then write in code.

Comment: @lokesh1729 can you provide sample value for labelfilteraction

Comment: I never worked with Gmail API I worked with sheets and drive, but if you go to `Request Body -> Add Property -> Label Filter Action` then hover your mouse on question mark, they provide the details, if not try googling with the phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I looked into this it wasn't working as documented.

My understanding is that you should be able to filter by label (not a custom label)

My experience was that we got notifications for all events unfortunately...

You can see our discussion here

[Gmail API Watch not filtering by Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591302/gmail-api-watch-not-filtering-by-label)

I know was Google working on fixing it...