# Issue with watch request on gmail api

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the below code to send a watch request to gmail. But it is sending push notifications for every action on the mailbox. I need google to send notifications if there is a new email received only. Otherwise I don't want google to send notifications. I am using google-api nodejs client. Can anyone please assist me on this?

```
watch (cb) {
const params = {
  userId: 'me',
  resource: {
    labelIds: ['INBOX'],
    labelFilterAction: 'include',
    topicName: configure.Google.TopicName
  }
};

this.gmail.users.watch(params, cb);
}
```

Comment: That should work. Are you sure you are getting every action? Maybe you just need to exclude `CATEGORY_PERSONAL`, `CATEGORY_SOCIAL`, etc.

Comment: this api is broken:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591302/gmail-api-watch-not-filtering-by-label
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43330396/gmail-api-watch-inbox-label-only
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37300052

Answer (score 0):

You can do `labelIds: ['UNREAD']`

When you go to request `history.list` with the historyId, there is an option to limit the messages returned to `messagesAdded`, though you will continue to get extraneous push notifications.

Comment: @JulioMarins it does work. don't downvote because you haven't debugged sufficiently. if you want more help, open a question and link it here and I'll give you a code snippet

Answer (score -2):

`labelIds` expects the id of the label, not the display name of it.

Comment: this isn't true. If that is the case, do you mind specifying where to find the label/id?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push it's not true