# Gmail API - Watch not sending filtered notifications

Tags: gmail-api

I have seen a couple of posts in StackOverflow related to this question but still they don't give me a concrete answer. So, posting a new question here.

I am trying to setup a watch on INBOX and SENT labels. Here is the code snippet I use

```
    WatchRequest watchReq = new WatchRequest();
    watchReq.setTopicName("mytopicgoeshere");
    List<String> labelIds = Arrays.asList("INBOX", "SENT");
    watchReq.setLabelIds(labelIds);
    watchReq.setLabelFilterAction("include");
    WatchResponse response = gmailService.users().watch(CURRENT_USER, watchReq).execute();
```

Though I specify the label ids and filter action correctly, I am still getting notification for all events not just for the labels I specified. Any idea how to get this working correctly? Any idea if it is a Google issue and fixed by them?

Comment: I think it is an expected behavior based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591302/gmail-api-watch-not-filtering-by-label). *You can filter the emails via LabelIds but you will receive notifications only if emails are directly being filtered to selected custom label.* It was also stated that watch seems to ignore them all and sends all events. If you think this is a bug, you may file a report [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/support).

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug with the GMail API. There is an entry for it on Google's Issue Tracker as linked below. Please star the issue to draw more attention to it:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759803

Comment: Thanks Dimu. I have starred it.