# Gmail API watch() request

Tags: push-notification, gmail, gmail-api

Gmail API watch() request doesn't filter messages by Label and I saw that it was known bug.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759803.

I want to know is there any other way to be notified when a new message is added under the label? And if there isn't any other way, please share some best practices for using watch request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gmail API Watch not filtering by Label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30591302/11683)